# Release some memory of a running Docker container on the fly

Tags: docker

Suppose there is a Docker container created with fixed memory configuration. Can I release some memory from it on the fly? Since we can do this with a simple command `lxc-cgroup -n name memory.limit_in_bytes 256M` in LXC.

Answer (score 4):

You can't release container memory without either:

1. Restarting the container
2. Clearing the host's memory

This is because Docker container's are represented as processes on the host system. Therefore you would need to free the memory associated with the container process. As far as I understand this is difficult especially since processes may rely on shared memory structures etc.

If you really need memory released you can use the following commands to help clear the hosts memory, assuming you are on Linux:

Flush data in memory buffers to disk:
`$ sync`

Clear OS page cache:
`$ echo 1 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches`

Comment: Yes, you are right. Some processes may share memory or most of the memory is occupied by running processes, so memory releasing is dangerous and unfeasible. But if there is low memory utilization in the container, is it possible?

Comment: A small terminology note, A container is not a process. A container is the context the process runs in. You can run multiple processes in that context. You can restart a process inside a container context. So the two are not always a 1 to 1 mapping. The process running in a container could have the ability to flush it's own memory, just as a process on the host can. But you are right in saying the container can't help the process do that.

Comment: Sorry for my poor expression, what I mean is some processes run in a container, not a container is a process.

Comment: @Matt Yes good point. You can run multiple processes in the container but there is typically only one long running process.

Answer (score 2):

A container on it's own doesn't use much memory. They are very light weight by design. Think of it as a fenced off area on your host, just a bit of tape to divide your container from the rest of the host.

The kernel has to house the cgroups, namespaces, interfaces, devices etc but this is negligible.

Docker itself will also introduce a small amount of overhead for it's management of the container but that is normally negligible (Unless you, say, map a thousand ports into a container).

The main use of memory will be the processes that run in the container. A container won't use 256MB if you set that as the upper limit, that will just be the upper limit before allocations start failing.

If you want to release used memory, either the process you are running in the container needs to have that ability, or you can restart the process using the memory.

Comment: Yes, what you say is the only right answer if I want to release memory proactively. Actually, when the upper memory limit of a container is set, it can use memory no more than the limit, when the ultilization is not 100%, the remain memory can also be used by other containers co-located on the same host. This is similar to memory ballon in Xen virtaulization tech.